# Creating a temporary copy of a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I would like to duplicate an existing UIView, with all of its subviews. The duplicated view is to be used as part of an animation, after which it will no longer be required.

I notice that UIView does not implement copyWithZone. Is there a simple way to create a view based on an existing view? Or will I need to manually set up the view using the parameters provided to the original view?

Alternatively, would it be better to create an image of the view and use this for my animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you need the entire view hierarchy? Can you just render the view into an image with -[CALayer renderInContext:] and use that?

Comment: I'm playing with renderInContext right now. One immediate issue is that the animation is triggered by a button press inside the view that is being copied. So, the image is captured with the button in its pressed state. I'll have a think about ways around this. I would like to use your suggestion if I can.

Comment: I'm waiting for an answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149687/waiting-for-uibutton-to-revert-to-uicontrolstatenormal

Comment: One way would be to create an image of the view before the button is pressed and just hold onto it until you need it.